# What are problems that arise by denying the existence of abstract things?

Tags: ontology

Suppose if we only regarded the concrete as real, and that abstraction is only a process of using the concrete to represent other concrete things. For example, a number is not a real thing, but it is the concrete object (mark, pixel, etc) that we use as a symbol that map to some configuration of other concrete objects, so that we can manipulate the symbols themselves to model and reason about the concrete.

Would this cause any contradictions with some first principles or common sense, or limit our ability to express or reason about the world?

Comment: The denial of abstract objects is called nominalism. Detailing its problems would take too much space to do here, please see online encyclopedias, e.g. [IEP](https://www.iep.utm.edu/universa/#H3).

Comment: @Conifold I believe OP is presenting a particular variation of Nominalism, therefore it is not necessarily broad. They are just inquiring if the said variation of Nominalism is problematic or not.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I do not see it, "abstraction is only a process of using the concrete to represent other concrete things" and "manipulate the symbols themselves to model and reason about the concrete" are as generic a description of *nomina* as it gets.

Comment: @Conifold I do not necessarily disagree with you on that. However, I am disagreeing that the question is (necessarily) broad. I think tailoring a general critique of nominalism such that it deals with OP's description of it will be a sufficient enough answer to the question. Regards